# alert controller not displaying in iphone using swift2

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift2, uialertcontroller

in my app i want to use alert controller so am using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class GPSTrackingManager: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var seenError : Bool = false

func startTracking() {

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("error occured:\(error)")


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //println("locations = \(locationManager)")
    let latValue = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
    let lonValue = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude

    print(latValue)
    print(lonValue)
    GoogleLat = latValue
    GoogleLong = lonValue
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks!.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

}
func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?)
{
    if let containsPlacemark = placemark
    {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let fourthcity = (containsPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea : ""
            let fourthState = (containsPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.administrativeArea : ""
            let fourthCountry = (containsPlacemark.country != nil) ? containsPlacemark.country : ""
            print("my Real City = \(fourthcity)")
            let fullName = fourthcity
            let fullNameArr = fullName!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
            fullNameArr[0]
            print(fullNameArr[0])
            print("myState = \(fourthState)")
            print("myCountry = \(fourthCountry)")
            appDelCityname = fullNameArr[0]
            appDelStateName = fourthState
            appDelCountryName = fourthCountry
            print("AppDelegate City Name = \(appDelCityname)")

    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .NotDetermined:
        // If status has not yet been determied, ask for authorization
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        // If authorized when in use
        print("AuthorizedWhenInUse")
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        // If always authorized
        print("AuthorizedAlways")
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .Denied:
        // If user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
        print("user denied to allow")
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
       NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0,target: self, selector: #selector(self.DisplayalertToturnonLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            })
        break
    default:
        print("user cant allow location service")
        break
    }
}

func DisplayalertToturnonLocation(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "GPRS is Required", message: "This app requires your location,please turn on your location service or set your address", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Set Address", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
        self.alertTogetAdrressFromUser()

    })
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
        (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)

    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let mainController = keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    mainController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

I am calling this function in AppDelegate which executes well in iPad but not in iPhone also it not shows any error or warning and  am feeling too difficult to find what am doing wrong here so any one help me to display alert controller in iPhone.

in AppDelegate:

```
var tracking = GPSTrackingManager()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 tracking.startTracking()
}
```

Comment: am just calling that function in appdelegate which works in ipad but not in iphone @anbu.karthik

Comment: @are you seen the duplicate answer, try once if you not get the output i reopen the question

Comment: why you marked this as duplicate other stackOverflow only has the question of how to display alert controller in appdelegate but see my question what am asked @anbu.karthik

Comment: already the duplicate answer has solve ur issue , in here you need to follow two things . 1. your code is fine you need to show ur alertcontroller using main thread, else find the root wihch one is most top presnt your alert, else check once your current window is visible or not

Comment: good this is the correct way, now i reopen

Comment: which displaying in ipad but not in iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in here you need to follow two things . 1. your code is fine you need to show ur alertcontroller using main thread, else find the root wihch one is most top presnt your alert, else check once your current window is visible or not
>
> present  your **UIAlertcontroller in Main thread**, for e.g

**Swift3**

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tracking.DisplayalertToturnonLocation()
    }
```

**swift2**

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tracking.DisplayalertToturnonLocation()
}
```

you get the output as

[image]

**full code**

```
class GPSTrackingManager: NSObject {

func DisplayalertToturnonLocation(){
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "GPRS is Required", message: "This app requires your location,please turn on your location service or set your address", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Set Address", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        alert -> Void in
      //  self.alertTogetAdrressFromUser()
        
    })
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
      //  UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! as URL)
        
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 
    
}
}
```